# get all changed files for a TFS workitem

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am working with Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2013.
Is it possible to obtain the list of files affected by a workitem?
Currently, using the Query Editor under Team menu, I am only able to get all the changests commited for a workitem but for a code-review it would be interesting to get also directly the list of affected files.

Answer (score 0):

In Source Control Explorer right click on a folder and on context menu "View History", will list all changeset's, select one and on Team Explorer show the informations about files changed.

You can get the same information by command line:

```
tf changeset /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection 123 /noprompt
```

to show the windows don't use "/noprompt" parameter.

Comment: That's not what @bandreas is after.  They're looking for a way to view all the files that changed in a work item without viewing each individual change set.  In a sense, to be able to diff the before and after of the effected files without having to look at the individual changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TFS Sidekicks. You can search for work item and it will give you a consolidated view.

1. Install sidekicks from http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/ for your relevant TFS version
2. Open side kicks and connect it to TFS (usual tfs dialogue)
3. Click Tools -> Code Review Sidekick
4. Click by Work Items and select the appropriate Project and Query (TFS explorer workitem query). Alternatively, you can search by changesets
5. Select the appropriate work item.
6. This will show all the changes for that workitem
7. So the goal here, you want to compare all of the changes to a file,
   from its state before the first checkin of this workitem and the
   last checkin of the workitem. i.e. collapse all of the changes
8. Right click the file you are reviewing, the one associates with the
   highest changeset number, and select 'compare with previous (not in
   view)'
9. This will show you the complete difference in your VS configured
   diff tool.
10. If the file is new and has multiple checkins, select the
    one with the maximum changeset it, and select 'compare with oldest
    in the view'