# Getting all changes for an issue #

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

If I go to Work Items-> All Work Item->Edit Query, And look for a specific Issue,  I can open that issue and see all links, which are all the changesets for that issue.  And if I look at each changeset I can figure out which files have changed.

But this can be confusing if there are a lot of changesets for an issue.  What  I really want is a consolidated list of all the files that have changed under an issue, with the ability to run a dif between the latest version under that issue compared with the version of that file before the issue.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be simply achieved through a work item query or tf command. You may have to use TFS API.

Detail steps should be Getting your Work Item for TFS server, then can  all of the Files/Items that were modified and associated with this Work Item, get all of the changeset from a collection of links (Links in a Work Item), list all files in those changsets.

```
/// <summary>
 /// Get all of the Files/Items that were modified and associated with a Work Item
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="teamProject">Name of the Team Project</param>
 /// <param name="workItemID">The work item ID</param>
 /// <returns>List of changes</returns>
 public List<FileItem> GetAllFilesModifiedForWorkItem(string teamProject, int workItemID)
 {
  WorkItemCollection workItems = GetWorkItems(teamProject, workItemID);

  if (workItems.Count == 0)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("No Items found for Work Item ID: " + workItemID);

   return null;
  }

  WorkItem item = workItems[0];

  Console.WriteLine("Work Item {0} has {1} Links", workItemID, item.Links.Count);

  if(item.Links.Count == 0)
   return null;

  List<Changeset> lstChangesets = GetChangesets(item.Links);

  Console.WriteLine("Work Item {0} has {1} Changesets", workItemID, lstChangesets.Count);

  if (lstChangesets.Count == 0)
   return null;

  List<FileItem> lstItems = GetItemsForChangeset(lstChangesets);

  Console.WriteLine("Work Item {0} has {1} Items (changes)", workItemID, lstItems.Count);

  if (lstItems.Count == 0)
   return null;

  return lstItems;
 }
```

The whole code and more detail info please refer this blog: [How to get all files modified for a work item in TFS](http://dyslexicanaboko.blogspot.sg/2014/01/how-to-get-all-files-modified-for-work.html)

Moreover, you can also try to use [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) which will also return all the changes for that workitem. Detail ways please refer jagberg's answer in this question: [get all changed files for a TFS workitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334903/get-all-changed-files-for-a-tfs-workitem)